# Stretching Divs to bottom of page in a container

Tags: css, html, liquid

I am trying to fix this page, http://blisshair.com.au/testing/.
What I am trying to do, is make the "menu" and "content" divs stretch to the bottom on the page.

This is the CSS, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks :)

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-color:#000;
}

.wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:#0F0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    min-height:80%;
}

.wrapper1{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background:url(bg.gif) 20% 0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.menu{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
}

.content{
    float:left;
    width:80%;
}

footer{
    width:100%;
}

header{
    width:100%;
}
```

Edit: I am trying to make the "content" and "menu" div's stretch to the length of the page, like as described here.

Comment: Is the aim here to get a footer at the bottom of the page like these answers are presuming, or to 'make the "menu" and "content" divs stretch to the bottom on the page' as you asked in your question?

Comment: hi, the aim is to make the menu and content divs stretch the length of the page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own experiences, this can only be done by JavaScript.

In my own applications, I used a timer and adjusted the height to the height of the main window.

This is how e.g. Google Calendar does it.

I recently [answered a similar question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942868/how-to-fill-div-with-full-height-of-page-in-css-page-is-taller-than-100-for-a/3942956#3942956).

Comment: Wrong answer, that is all. It can be done without javascript. I removed the -1.

Comment: Thanks, @sinelaw - I understand that the sticking can be done without JavaScript. Can the stretching be done also without JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry Uwe Keim, technically you're right, but in practice the sticky footer approach makes the content always look as if it takes up the entire height at least, and the footer is at the bottom. I was guessing that is what Nik needed.

Comment: hey thanks for the javascript idea, is there no way to do this with CSS? if not ill definately add this, the only downside is I have no clue in regards to javascript, and was hoping that with a CSS solution I'd be able to learn it for next time, but if there is no alternative I will definately add this, thanks!

Comment: I'm not _that_ expert. My assumption on these kind of things is: Google does it; Google definitely _knows_ what's working on virtually all platforms; I'll do it like Google then :-)

Answer (score 2):

You may try [CSSStickyFooter](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/), no JavaScript is required.